# List of lists into tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

(Python) I'm a beginner and need to change my list of lists into a tuple of tuples.

```
 Input->  myList=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]
 Output-> ((0,0),(0,1),(2,2),(1,2))
```

The first thing I'm trying to do is to split my list of lists, but I keep getting an Attribute Error.

```
    myList = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]
    myList = [item[0].split(",") for item in myList]
    print(myList)
```

any help?

Comment: `.split` is `str`'s method list has no method called `split`. You can use `map` here. `tuple(map(tuple,myList))` You will get the desired output

Comment: You can't split lists, only strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert your sublists into tuples.

```py
tuple(tuple(item) for item in myList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` + `tuple`

```
tuple(map(tuple, myList))
#((0, 0), (0, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
tuple([ tuple(x) for x in myList ])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myList=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]

mytuple = tuple([tuple(elem) for elem in myList])

print(mytuple)
```